# array con diferente clases c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un proyecto que realizar, resulta que tengo 5 clases de las cuales derivan 2 de cada una y necesito que se ordenen. En principio pense en un array, pero después vi que el compilador sólo me dejaba usar un array por clase por lo que cuando necesitaba usar herencia no podía. Entonces mi pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo meter objetos de las 15 clases que tengo en un array o en algo parecido?.

Dejo un poco de codigo de referencia abajo:

```
class luchador{};

class caballero::luchador{};

class Paladin::Luchador{};

void main{

    Luchador L[NJ+NOp];
    Caballero C;
    Paladin P;
    L[0] =  C;
    L[1] = P;
}
```

Y así usar L para ordenar las clases.

Answer (score 1):

- Respuesta corta: **no puedes**.

  Las formaciones tienen esa limitación: todos los elementos han de tener el mismo tamaño. Además, han de tener constructor sin argumentos.
- Respuesta larga: *hecha la ley, hecha la trampa*.

  1. Si todas tus clases tienen el mismo tamaño, puedes hacerlo. **Pero** desde el punto de vista del compilador, todos los elementos serán del mismo tipo, por lo que tienes que idear alguna forma de *distinguir* unas instancias de otras. Y llenar tu código con *feos* y *propensos a errores* moldeados de tipos (*casting*):

     ```
     MyClass1 arr[10];
     arr[9].~MyClass1( );
     arr[9] = new ( &arr[9] ) MyClass2( );

     reinterpret_cast< MyClass2 * >( &arr[9] )->metodoDeClass2( );
     ```
  2. Alternativamente, si tienes un diseño de clase poco menos que perfecto, puedes utilizar funciones virtuales para ahorrarte los *casting*.
  3. Si te sientes especialmente inspirado ese día, puedes utilizar `union` ... con todo lo que ello implica. Sería recomendable usar una clase auxiliar ... pero con 15 clases ... va a ser extraordinariamente *divertido* :-)
- Respuesta **práctica**: usa una formación de punteros:

  Usar punteros + funciones virtuales es la solución que menos dolores de cabeza te dará. El inconveniente es que las clases han de tener una clase base común:

  ```
  class Base { ... };
  class Hija1 : public Base { ... };
  class Hija2 : public Base { ... };
  class SubHija1_1 : public Hija1 { ... };

  Base *arr[10] = { 0 };

  arr[0] = new Hija1( );
  arr[1] = new Hija2( );
  arr[2] = new SubHija1_1( );
  ```
- Respuesta **real**: usa **varias** formaciones de punteros.

  O, mejor aún, usar varios contenedores (no formaciones), como `std::list< >` o `std::map< >`. El uso de `std::vector< >` está desaconsejado en escenarios con altas tasas de creación/destrucción de elementos, debido a las operaciones de copia subyacentes:

  ```
  std::list< Enemigo > ListaEnemigos;
  std::list< Disparo > ListaDisparos;
  std::map< std::string, MapaDeHabitacion > MapaDeHabitaciones;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Cómo puedo meter objetos de las 15 clases que tengo en un array o en algo parecido?

Olvida el array, vamos a por "*algo parecido*".

---

Los contenedores de datos estándar de C++ son homogéneos, es decir: sólo contienen un tipo de datos, pero en tu caso estás usando herencia:

> Tengo 5 clases de las cuales derivan 2 de cada una.

Eso es bueno, puedes tener contenedores de la clase base:

```
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct Base1 { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base2 { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base3 { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base4 { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base5 { virtual void f() = 0; };

struct D11 : public Base1 { void f() { P; } };
struct D12 : public Base1 { void f() { P; } };
struct D21 : public Base2 { void f() { P; } };
struct D22 : public Base2 { void f() { P; } };
struct D31 : public Base3 { void f() { P; } };
struct D32 : public Base3 { void f() { P; } };
struct D41 : public Base4 { void f() { P; } };
struct D42 : public Base4 { void f() { P; } };
struct D51 : public Base5 { void f() { P; } };
struct D52 : public Base5 { void f() { P; } };

int main()
{
    /* Usamos vectores como contenedor, cada vector contendrá un
       puntero inteligente a la clase base. */
    using B1 = std::unique_ptr<Base1>;
    using B2 = std::unique_ptr<Base2>;

    using A1 = std::vector<B1>;
    using A2 = std::vector<B2>;

    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;

    // Guardamos diferentes derivadas en el mismo contenedor:
    a1.push_back(B1{new D11});
    a1.push_back(B1{new D12});

    a2.push_back(B2{new D21});
    a2.push_back(B2{new D22});

    for (const auto &v : a1)
        v->f();

    for (const auto &v : a2)
        v->f();

    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior muestra](https://wandbox.org/permlink/38lUUjALdEUJ1PGe):

> ```
> virtual void D11::f()
> virtual void D12::f()
> virtual void D21::f()
> virtual void D22::f()
> ```

Pero esto no te permite guardar las 15 clases en un solo contenedor, porque sólo puedes agrupar de tres en tres (base y sus derivadas), si quisieras guardar en un solo contenedor podrías usar una clase común:

#### Super Clase Base.

Si todas las Base derivan de otra base, puedes hacer un contenedor de todas ellas:

```
#define P std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };

//             vvvvvvvvvvvv <--- Base de todas las bases
struct Base1 : public Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base2 : public Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base3 : public Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base4 : public Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };
struct Base5 : public Madre { virtual void f() = 0; };
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Base de todas las bases

struct D11 : public Base1 { void f() { P; } };
struct D12 : public Base1 { void f() { P; } };
struct D21 : public Base2 { void f() { P; } };
struct D22 : public Base2 { void f() { P; } };
struct D31 : public Base3 { void f() { P; } };
struct D32 : public Base3 { void f() { P; } };
struct D41 : public Base4 { void f() { P; } };
struct D42 : public Base4 { void f() { P; } };
struct D51 : public Base5 { void f() { P; } };
struct D52 : public Base5 { void f() { P; } };

int main()
{
    using M = std::unique_ptr<Madre>;
    using A = std::vector<M>;

    A a;

    a.push_back(M{new D11});
    a.push_back(M{new D12});
    a.push_back(M{new D21});
    a.push_back(M{new D22});

    for (const auto &v : a)
        v->f();

    return 0;
}
```

[El código anterior muestra](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7BehQH8eKv7Gu4oh):

> ```
> virtual void D11::f()
> virtual void D12::f()
> virtual void D21::f()
> virtual void D22::f()
> ```